# Angular Slide In, Slide Out Animations

Tags: angular, animation

I was thinking that a slide in, slide out, animation would be a pretty standard thing to do in Angular (using version 8.x at the moment), but I'm not able to find any examples to help get me over a hurdle I'm facing. I've tinkered with some basics and can slide an item in, but sliding it out and then sliding in the next item are not happening as I'd expect.

My current test animation:

```
animations: [
trigger('slideAnimation', [
  transition('* => slideInFromLeft', [
    animate('400ms ease-in', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' }))
  ]),
  transition('* => slideInFromRight', [
    animate('400ms ease-in', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' }))
  ]),
  transition('* => slideOutLeft', [
    animate('400ms ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }))
  ]),
  transition('* => slideOutRight', [
    animate('400ms ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }))
  ])
])
```

]

Can someone give me some suggestions to fix my test animation, or point me towards an example that shows:

- Slide in from left, slide out to right
- Slide in from right, slide out to left

Think **PREV** and **NEXT** button type of animations.

Thanks!

Comment: Just in case if you can use pure CSS solutions - use https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/. It has pre-defined animations including slide in/out. Why to re-invent the wheel

Comment: Seems useful. Only problem was that when testing in Chrome and Firefox, the defaults seem to have it disabled (Safari and Edge were fine). I'd rather not require folks to change their browser settings just to let the animation work.